# Number of ways to draw 4 balls from a box which contains 3 red balls and 2 yellow balls? (without replacement)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Question:

> What are the number of ways to draw 4 balls from a box which contains
> 3 red balls and 2 yellow balls (without replacement)

My attempt:

> You can either choose 3 red balls and 1 yellow ball OR 2 red balls and 2
> yellow balls so the answer should be: $$3C3*2C1+3C2*3C2 = 5$$

However, tree diagram shows otherwise (number of ways to draw 4 balls = 10) so I must be wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe from the question that the balls are indistinguishable (aside from color) and that the number of ways to draw something requires that different orders of drawing are counted different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, there are $2$ ways to draw $4$ balls. Either draw $3$ red balls and $1$ yellows, or $2$ red balls and $2$ yellows.

In the first case, There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to order the sequence of $4$ balls.

In the first case, There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to order the sequence of $4$ balls.

Hence, the total is $\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{2}=4+6=\boxed{10}$

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the original question?

Case 1: picking order doesn't matter. Think about the complement. When you pick up 4 balls, there is only one ball left. If balls are all distinguishable, there are 5 ways. If balls are indistinguishable except for colors, then there are only two ways.

Case 2: Picking order matters. If balls are indistinguishable except for colors, then there are $\frac{5!}{3!2!}=10$ ways to sort them. Most likely this is the intention of the original question asks. If all balls are distinguishable, then there are $5!$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that selecting and placing is the same , so for being it easy ,lets think that we want to put $4$ balls into an urn using $3$ identical red balls and $2$ identical yellow balls.

Now , generating functions is suitable ways to use.

- Generating function of red balls is $$(1+x+x^2 +x^3)$$
- Generating function of yellow balls is $$(1+x+x^2 )$$

Now , you must find the coefficient of $x^4$ in the expansion of $$(1+x+x^2 +x^3) \times (1+x+x^2 )$$

Then , *[CALCULATION](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%28x+%2B+1+%2Bx%5E2+%2Bx%5E3%29%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%29)*

So ,answer is $2$

If the selection order matters and balls are ideantical among themselves then:

-Exponential Generating function of red balls is $$(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} +\frac{x^3}{3!})$$

-Exponential Generating function of yellow balls is $$(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} )$$

*[CALCULATION](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%28x+%2B+1+%2Bx%5E2+%2F2+%2Bx%5E3+%2F+6%29%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2+%2F2%29)*

Then , $$4! \times \frac{5}{12} =10$$

If the balls were **different** among themselves , then

- Generating function of red balls is $$\bigg(1+\frac{P(3,1)x^1}{1!}+\frac{P(3,2)x^2}{2!}+\frac{P(3,3)x^3}{3!}\bigg)=(1+x)^3$$
- Generating function of yellow balls is $$\bigg(1+\frac{P(2,1)x^1}{1!}+\frac{P(2,2)x^2}{2!} \bigg)=(1+x)^2$$

Find the coefficient of $x^4$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^3(1+x)^2$ and multiply it by $4!$

Then , *[CALCULATION](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2B3x%2B3x%5E2+%2Bx%5E3%29%281%2B2x%2Bx%5E2%29)*

Answer is $5 \times 24 =120$

Comment: Hi, buddy ! Is it possible to set up a g.f. over non-negative integers for $a+b+c = 18, a<b, b<2c$ ?

Comment: @trueblueanil hi my friend! Yes it seems possible in the first glance, but today i am busy for MSE. When i find free time, i can answer it if you want

Comment: Ok, whenever you are free, the little bit I know about g.f.s is all because of you ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: @trueblueanil hi buddy, I worked over the question today, but i think it is somewhat hard to construct a generating function on it. Using python, i found that answer is $44$. If I can find a way for it, i will ping you in the future. However, you can open a question for it, the community may help

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't matter, the  particular question is small enough to be evaluated even manually, I was just curious whether such a problem can be handled by a g.f. I tried doubling the variables with a sum of $36$, but it gave an incorrect answer of $47$

Comment: @trueblueanil I solved it now :) Let me write the answer in the orginal question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802745/how-many-nonnegative-integer-solutions-x-1-x-2-x-3-18-x-1x-2-and-x

Comment: @trueblueanil look at the link

Comment: Yea, good show from the g.f. enthusiast ! (+1)