# How many nonnegative integer solutions $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 18$, $x_1<x_2$ and $x_2 < 2x_3$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, combinations

Consider the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 18$

Where $x_1<x_2$ and $x_2 < 2x_3$

$x_1,x_2,x_3\ge0$

How many non negative solutions does this equation have?

Comment: Hint: stars-and-bars and inclusion-exclusion

Comment: pls show the detil solutions. Thx

Comment: Strange problem, where I disagree with the suggestion of @RobPratt.  Although Stars and Bars and Inclusion-Exclusion is definitely the way to go, to learn the tools that will help with this generic type of problem, this specific problem can be more easily attacked via brute force.  **Hint:** $~x_2 > x_1~$ and $~x_2 < \dfrac{18-x_1}{3}.$

Comment: "Please show the details..." : Can't, because your posting is missing several details, and is therefore of low quality.  Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: $x_1, x_2, x_3 ≥ 0$

Comment: @RobPratt I dont think that this is classical stars and bars problem with P.I.E , inequality signs make it harder

Comment: @UntungPermadi where did you find this question ?

Comment: i got this question from math competition for junior high schools held by a university in Indonesia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you did not show any effort, I think that answering this interesting question may help other users in M.S.E,so I am sorry for breaking the rule of the site.

In this question , I will make use of the power of generating functions. It is said that $x_1 < x_2$ and $x_2 < 2x_3$. Then, let $a,b \in Z^{\geq1}$ such that $x_2=x_1+a$ and $2x_3=x_2+b$, then accoring to this equalities $2x_3=x_1+a+b$.

Now, if $x_1+x_2+x_3=18$, then $2x_1+2x_2+2x_3=36$. By using foregoing equalities $$2x_1+2(x_1+a)+(x_1+a+b)=36$$ $$5x_1+3a+b=36$$ So, using ordinary generating functions : $$[x^{36}]\bigg(\frac{1}{1-x^5}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{x}{1-x}\bigg)=44$$

[CALCULATION](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2F%281-x%5E5%29%29%28x%5E3%2F%281-x%5E3%29%29%28x%2F%281-x%29%29)

You can see it using the following python code:

```
count = 0
for c in range(1, 19):
    for a in range(0, 2*c):
        b = 18 - a - c
        if b > a and b < 2*c:
            print("a =", a, "b =", b, "c =", c)
            count += 1
print("Total number of solutions:", count)
```

Comment: thanks for the explaination, it's really helpful